# Can I "mark all as read" in Riot?

Tags: chat, riot.im

I am using a Riot web instance (I assume the answer will also apply to the Electron desktop client). I have joined some rooms that I don't follow closely, and have several days of chat I don't intend to read.

Is it possible to "mark all as read"? In other words, all rooms and chats that I have joined are considered "read" and no longer show an unread counter.

Answer (score 3):

No there isn’t a way to do that. You can thumbs up and subscribe to the following issues:

- https://github.com/vector-im/riot-web/issues/8666 for marking individual rooms as read
- https://github.com/vector-im/riot-web/issues/850 for marking all rooms as read

Answer (score 0):

To mark a **single room** as read and jump to the bottom of that room, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>. (This was added in [PR#4271](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-react-sdk/pull/4271).)

As described in [ticket 850](https://github.com/vector-im/element-web/issues/850) you can mark **all rooms** as read by clicking the Clear Notifications button. It's not clear from the linked tickets if a keyboard shortcut is planned.